# How to highlight / mark as important / make a list of some wordpress posts? Exist any plugin?

Tags: wordpress, list, post, plugins

I want to mark as important some wordpress posts, and after it I want to see these posts as a link list at the beginning of each page (like when you mark a post as static: post options -> visibility). And change this the list order, the content...

So, I can start to think how to do a plugin but previously I want to know if there is already done a plugin which does what I want.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

obviously, it's related to the theme style, not plugin. you just put some tag like "special" for your important posts, then from your theme:

```
 <?php query_posts('tag=special');if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <h3>Important : <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
 <?php endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

it's just the principle, hope that helps.

/*i have edited the above*/

Comment: Ok, was missing the parentheses: the_post()
I am trying.